# geocode don't show subpremise address Brazil

Tags: geocode

how to collect room number information on a building in the google geocode?
in my search don't show. SUBPREMISE

example address: rua joao samaha 1385, sala 403 bl 02 sao joao batista, belo horizonte, MG, Brazil.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=

Comment: Is that the part that says `apartment 403 bl 02`, or is it a slightly different substring?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer at SmartyStreets, an international address verification API provider. Here's the component information that we have on that address:

```
[
   {
      // preceding data omitted
      "components":{
         "administrative_area":"MG",
         "building":"Bloco 02",
         "dependent_locality":"São João Batista (Venda Nova)",
         "country_iso_3":"BRA",
         "locality":"Belo Horizonte",
         "postal_code":"31520-100",
         "postal_code_short":"31520-100",
         "premise":"1385",
         "premise_number":"1385",
         "thoroughfare":"Rua João Samaha",
         "thoroughfare_name":"Joao Samaha",
         "thoroughfare_type":"Rua",
         "building_leading_type":"Bloco",
         "sub_building_type":"Sala",
         "sub_building_number":"403"
      },
      // remaining data omitted
   }
]
```

Does that information help?

https://smartystreets.com/docs/international#components